# spinner selected value returns to old value when recyclerview row is clicked

Tags: android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, spinner

i have created an android application using xamarin.android. the application has a recyclerview that contains a spinner. what i want is when the user selects an item from the spinner, i need to change the value of the corresponding column and row in the datatable and i need the new value to be displayed in the spinner in the recyclerview in the row where the spinner value is selected. the problem is that whenever a value is selected, when another row is clicked, the old value of the spinner is displayed. i tried a lot of ways like the code in the following link: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1033283/android-recycler-view-with-spinner-item-change-sel, but it didn't work. this is my code:

```
public class recyclerview_viewholder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            public TextView rownbr, laborname;
            public EditText  overtime;
            public LinearLayout linearLayout;
            public Spinner days;


            public recyclerview_viewholder(View itemView, Action<int> listener)
              : base(itemView)
            {
                rownbr = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.rownbr);
                laborname = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.laborname);
                days = itemView.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.days);
                overtime = itemView.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.overtime);
                linearLayout = itemView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayout);
                
                itemView.Click += (sender, e) => listener(base.LayoutPosition);

               
            }
 public class recyclerviewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
        {
            // Event handler for item clicks:
            public event EventHandler<int> ItemClick;
           // public event EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs> SpinnerItemSelectionChanged;

            public static DataTable summary_Requests = new DataTable();
            //Context context;
            public readonly new_schedule context;
            public static int selected_pos = -1;
            RecyclerView recyclerView;
            FloatingActionButton delete;
            public recyclerviewAdapter(new_schedule context, DataTable sum_req, RecyclerView recyclerView)
            {
                this.context = context;
                summary_Requests = sum_req;
                this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
                
            }
            public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder
                   OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
            {
                View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).
                            Inflate(Resource.Layout.recycler_view_new_schedule_data, parent, false);


                recyclerview_viewholder vh = new recyclerview_viewholder(itemView, OnClick);
  vh.days.ItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
                    int position = Convert.ToInt32(spinner.Tag);
                    summary_Requests.Rows[position]["dayNbr"] = Convert.ToDecimal(spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position).ToString());
                  

                };


                vh.overtime.TextChanged += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (vh.overtime.Text != "")

                        try
                        {
                            int position = vh.LayoutPosition;
                            summary_Requests.Rows[position]["overtimeHours"] = Convert.ToInt32(vh.overtime.Text);
                            user.zero_val = "Not_exist";
                        }
                        catch (System.FormatException exp)
                        {
                            var icon = AppCompatResources.GetDrawable(context.Context, Resource.Drawable.error_ic);
                            icon.SetBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);
                            vh.overtime.SetError("unit must be integer not decimal", icon);
                            user.zero_val = "exits";
                        }
                    else if (vh.overtime.Text == "")
                    {
                        var icon = AppCompatResources.GetDrawable(context.Context, Resource.Drawable.error_ic);
                        icon.SetBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);
                        vh.overtime.SetError("value can not be empty", icon);
                        user.zero_val = "exits";
                    }

                };

                
                return vh;
            }

           

            public override void
                  OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
            {
                recyclerview_viewholder vh = holder as recyclerview_viewholder;

                vh.rownbr.Text = summary_Requests.Rows[position]["rowNumber"].ToString();
                vh.laborname.Text = summary_Requests.Rows[position]["laborerName"].ToString();
                List<decimal> days_data = new List<decimal>();
                days_data.Add((decimal)0.5);
                days_data.Add((decimal)1);
                var adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this.context.Context, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, days_data);
                adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
                vh.days.Tag = position;
                vh.days.Adapter = adapter;
                vh.days.SetSelection(1);
                vh.overtime.Text = summary_Requests.Rows[position]["overtimeHours"].ToString();

                if (selected_pos == position)
                    vh.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor("#4fa5d5"));
                else
                    vh.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.LightGray);

                vh.ItemView.Click += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    int pos = vh.LayoutPosition;
                    user.del_pos = position;
                    
                    selected_pos = position;
                    NotifyDataSetChanged();
                    //fill global variables that need to be passed to detail fragment



                };



                //delete.Click += delegate
                //{
                //    vh.days.Enabled = false;

                //};
            }

           
            public DataTable get_dt_final()
            {
                DataTable final_dt = summary_Requests.Copy();
                return final_dt;
            }

            public override long GetItemId(int position)
            {
                return position;
            }
            public void deleteItem(int index)
            {
                summary_Requests.Rows.RemoveAt(index);
                NotifyItemRemoved(index);
            }

            public override int ItemCount
            {
                get { return summary_Requests.Rows.Count; }
            }
            // Raise an event when the item-click takes place:
            void OnClick(int position)
            {
                if (ItemClick != null)
                    ItemClick(this, position);
                // user.req_pos = position;


            }
  }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I read the article that you provide, you need to do two things when you change spinner value, firstly, you need to change `vegeList's` itemPosition quantity by `SpinnerItemSelectionChangedEvent`, then you need to update `TotalAmount` in `OnBindViewHolder`

```
private void SpinnerItemSelectionChangedEvent(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
        var itemPosition = Convert.ToInt32(spinner.Tag);
        //Update the view by Total Amount, after spinner value is been selected.
        var currentquantity = vegeList[itemPosition].Quantity;
        var selectedQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position).ToString());
        if (currentquantity != selectedQuantity)
        {
            vegeList[itemPosition].Quantity = selectedQuantity;
            Madapter.NotifyItemChanged(itemPosition);
        }
    }

public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        var item = Items[position];

        var vh = holder as VegeViewHolder;
        var spinnerPos = 0;
        var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Context, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, _quantity);
        adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);

        vh.Name.Text = item.Name;
        vh.Price.Text = string.Format("Price: ${0}", item.Price);
        vh.ItemView.Tag = position;
        if (item.Quantity > 0)
        {
            spinnerPos = adapter.GetPosition(item.Quantity.ToString());
            vh.TotalAmount.Text = string.Format("${0}", item.Price * item.Quantity);
        }
        else
        {
            vh.TotalAmount.Text = "";
        }
        vh.Quantity.Tag = position; //keep reference to list view row position
        vh.Quantity.Adapter = adapter;
        vh.Quantity.SetSelection(spinnerPos);
        vh.Image.SetImageResource(item.ImageId);
    }
```

[image]